# AbortError: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed

Tags: node.js, redis-cluster

We keep getting Error messages on our Server logs that the Redis connection has been lost and command aborted. We are using Express JS and trying to connect to Redis Cluster.

```
 AbortError: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed.
at RedisClient.flush_and_error (/var/www/project/stg/node_modules/redis/index.js:362:23)
at RedisClient.connection_gone (/var/www/project/stg/node_modules/redis/index.js:664:14)
at RedisClient.on_error (/var/www/project/stg/node_modules/redis/index.js:410:10)
at Socket.anonymous (/var/www/project/stg/node_modules/redis/index.js:279:14)
at Socket.emit (events.js:210:5)
at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8)
at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:60:3)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
```

Comment: Seems like your connection is not stable, will you please post your network graph between your server and redis. Is there any other service being configured on server over the network and that is running find and you are facing issue only for redis ?

Comment: May be too late but I had this error too.
The problem was that TLS was enabled on the redis server but the URL that I was using to connect was `redis//` instead of `rediss//`.
You may want to check that if you're in this situation